# How to convert a Tensor with shape (None, 512) into a Tensor with shape (None, 12, 12, 512)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using Python 3.7.7., Tensorflow 2.1.0 and Functional Api to define an encoder with this summary:

```
Model: "encoder"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 200, 200, 1)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 200, 200, 64)      1664      
_________________________________________________________________
conv1_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 200, 200, 64)      102464    
_________________________________________________________________
pool1 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 100, 100, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 100, 100, 96)      55392     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 100, 100, 96)      83040     
_________________________________________________________________
pool2 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 50, 50, 96)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv3_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 50, 50, 128)       110720    
_________________________________________________________________
conv3_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 50, 50, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
pool3 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 25, 25, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv4_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 25, 25, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
conv4_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 25, 25, 256)       1048832   
_________________________________________________________________
pool4 (MaxPooling2D)         (None, 12, 12, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv5_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 12, 12, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
conv5_2 (Conv2D)             (None, 12, 12, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d (Gl (None, 512)               0         
=================================================================
Total params: 5,384,832
Trainable params: 5,384,832
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

I get the encoder from a U-Net network with this code:

```
u_net: Model = get_unet_uncompiled(img_shape = (200, 200, 1))

encoder_input = Model(inputs=u_net.layers[0].input, outputs=u_net.layers[14].output)
encoder_output = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(encoder_input.layers[-1].output)

encoder = Model(encoder_input.input, encoder_output, name='encoder')

print(encoder.summary())
```

I want to up pooling its output to a shape of `(None, 12, 12, 512)`.

I have tried this:

```
u_net: Model = get_unet_uncompiled(img_shape = (200, 200, 1))

encoder_input = Model(inputs=u_net.layers[0].input, outputs=u_net.layers[14].output)
encoder_output = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(encoder_input.layers[-1].output)

up = UpSampling2D(size=(12, 12))(encoder_output)

encoder = Model(encoder_input.input, up, name='encoder')
```

But I have this error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer up_sampling2d is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 512]
```

**I have no idea about what I'm doing**. Maybe `UpSampling2D` is wrong here.

But, how can I convert it to shape `(None, 12, 12, 512)`?

Comment: If you just remove the global average pooling layer, your output will be `(None, 12, 12, 512)`

Comment: @NicolasGervais Thanks, but I need to do the global average pooling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Lambda layer:

```
import tensorflow as tf

inputs = tf.random.uniform((100, 512),0, 1, dtype=tf.int32)

layer = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.tile(tf.reshape(x, (100, 1, 1, 512)), 
                                                 (1, 12, 12, 1)))

print(layer(inputs).shape)
```

```
TensorShape([100, 12, 12, 512])
```

Answer (score 1):

[Deconvolution/ Upsamping](https://medium.com/@naokishibuya/up-sampling-with-transposed-convolution-9ae4f2df52d0) operation forms the same connectivity as the normal convolution but in the backward direction. For, [Upsampling in Keras](https://keras.io/api/layers/reshaping_layers/up_sampling2d/) input shape is

4D tensor with shape: - If data_format is "channels_last": (batch_size, rows, cols,channels)

But, you give output global_average_pooling2d  layer that is a  2D tensor ([None, 512]), so this throws the error. **If you want to use Upsamping here you should remove the Global Average Pooling layer, then upsampling will work.** [This](https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet/blob/master/model.py) is an example of UNet implemented from scratch in Keras.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but as I said in my question: "I don't know what I'm doing". I have tried with `UpSampling2D` but I think this is wrong for this. And, by the way, I have my U-Net created from scratch, just look how I have created the encoder_input: `encoder_input = Model(inputs=u_net.layers[0].input, outputs=u_net.layers[14].output)`